# How to get individual chunks from std::chunk_by return value?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I have the following c++23 code, which compiles with `gcc-13.2`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

auto main() -> int
{
    using std::cout;
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1};
    auto chunks = v | std::views::chunk_by(std::equal_to{});
    for (auto chunk : chunks)
    {
        cout << "[";
        for (const auto& value : chunk)
        {
            cout << value << ", ";
        }
        cout << "]\n";
    }
    cout << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
[1, ]
[2, 2, 2, ]
[1, 1, 1, ]
[2, ]
[1, ]
```

as expected.

But I want to get only say the second entry in that list (`[2, 2, 2, ]`) from `chunks`. How can I do that?

I tried indexing with `operator[]`, but that gives me a compiler error, as does `at()`. I tried `chunks.begin() + 1`, but that also doesn't compile. I can use  `| std::views::drop(1) | std::views::take(1)`, but that's clunky and there surely is a better way to do this.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `|drop(1)|take(1)` is how I'd do it.

Comment: `std::next(chunks.begin(), 1)` (as for any non-random-access iterator)?

Comment: @Jarod42 that works

Comment: @Jarod42 the 2nd parameter is optional when 1 is used: `std::next(chunks.begin())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried `chunks.begin() + 1`

That only works for random access iterator,
you have to use `std::next(chunks.begin(), 1)` (or `std::next(chunks.begin())`) instead.